# How to see root user processes in Activity Monitor?

Tags: macos, user-account, activity-monitor

I am wondering how to show the root user processes in Activity Monitor. On my mac, my personal user and root user show up, but on my sister's mac, only her personal user processes show up in Activity Monitor. How do I also show the root user in Activity Monitor in addition to other users' processes?

Below are the pictures of my computer and my sister's Activity Monitor. The dark one is mine with the root user (and other users not shown), and the light one is my sister's, without root user.

[image: root user shown]

[image: root user not shown]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View menu > All Processes

Default is just My Processes.